# Is there a way to restrict Google Sign In to a certain email domain in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-signin

Is there a way to restrict Google signIn in the app to certain emails with domain *@companyname.com*?

The goal is to let only *@companyname.com* users only to gain access in the log in features.

I have done some research but I have come up with nothing yet.

Comment: You can check the mail in the app and you can call signing in action if it is verified (Though Not sure how efficient and secure this method is)

Comment: you may follow this way -
in app develop custom login screen (which is looked like google sign in)and check every email not contain gmail.com instead of other emails are companyname emails , then after develop api and create google sign in from Backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need To Check This After Signing In That Will Be A Secure Way To Do It

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
           Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
           if (result.isSuccess()) {
               // Signed in successfully.
               GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
               String email = acct.getEmail();
               String[] split = s.split("@");
               String domain = split[1]; //This Will Give You The Domain After '@'
               if(domain.equals("companyname.com"))
               {
                 //Proceed Ahead.
               }
                else
               {
                 //Show User Warning UI.
               }
           } else {
               // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
               updateUI(false);
           }
       }
```

Comment: As published in their new book "You Need To Check This After Signing In That Will Be A Secure Way To Do It"